# Manage the sparkContext for test and normal execution

Tags: java, apache-spark

I like defining the spark context of my applications in an enumeration as follow:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;

public enum SparkGlobalContext {
    INSTANCE;
    
    private final SparkContext sparkContext = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("my-app"));
    private final JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkContext);
    private final SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext);

    public JavaSparkContext getJavaSparkContext() {
        return javaSparkContext;
    }

    public SQLContext getSqlContext() {
        return sqlContext;
    }
}
```

It allows me to access it everywhere in my app without having to extract it from an eventual rdd/dataframe when I need it.

The issue is that I assume that the master will always be passed from the spark-submit or the spark.conf. Yet in my unit test I would also like to have a spark context but I don't run it from a spark -submit command, I run it directly in the test such as:

```
public class TestQuoteTypeProcedureMapper implements Serializable {
    private transient final SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("test");
    private transient final SparkContext sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf);
    private transient final JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkContext);

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The error I get if I do this is that when I run the test, Java still run instantiate the enum that was presented above, but it fails to do so because the master isn't set.

But I don't like it.

Is there anything I should do ?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base will be useful?

Comment: In the end I found a very simple of doing it. I just removed the SparkConf from the enum and I call a method to init it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a simple solution.

```
public enum SparkGlobalContext {
INSTANCE;

private JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext;
private SQLContext sqlContext;

public void initSparkContext(SparkConf sparkConf) {
    if (this.javaSparkContext == null) {
        this.javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkContext(sparkConf));
        this.sqlContext = new SQLContext(this.javaSparkContext);
    }
}

public JavaSparkContext getJavaSparkContext() {
    return javaSparkContext;
}

public SQLContext getSqlContext() {
    return sqlContext;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I know you already answered your own question, but FWIW we just use the following in unit tests:

```
class FooTest {

   private SparkSession sparkSession;
   private Foo sut;

   @BeforeEach
   void setup() {
      ...
      sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
         .appName(this.getClass().getSimpleName())
         .master("local[4]")   // four local threads
         .getOrCreate();

      sut.sparkSession = sparkSession;
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't work in my initial case. The enum I declare containing my sparkContext would expect the config master and appName from the spark-submit that aren't specified when i run the test. Or at least I don't know how.

Comment: Hmm, ok. In our more complicated applications we just use CDI and inject the sparkContext wherever it is needed. In my example above, class Foo would have an instance variable declared as `@Inject SparkSession sparkSession;`. You need to add [JBoss Weld SE](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#weld-se) to your project for this to work.

Comment: I see, this correspond more to my case. Yet I would prefer not using an additional patform (?) when i can do it with an enum. But thx a lot for the suggestion I will look into it.

Comment: Ah, but think of all the other stuff you can @Inject. We also use [MicroProfile Config](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-config-2.0/microprofile-config-spec-2.0.html).